# How to insert variable to database table sqlite3 - Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Whenever i try to run the following code i get an error saying that theres no such column "title_data", im really confused because "TITLE" is the column not "title_data"

```
def insertData(self):
    title_Data = self.edit_title.text()
    year_Data = self.edit_year.text()
    rating_Data = self.edit_rating.text()


    connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
    try:
        connection.execute("INSERT INTO FILMS (TITLE,YEAR,RATING) VALUES(title_Data,year_Data,rating_Data)")


    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        print("You have already stored this data")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing your variables correctly. Instead of

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO FILMS (TITLE,YEAR,RATING) VALUES(title_Data,year_Data,rating_Data)")
```

You should use

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO FILMS (TITLE,YEAR,RATING) VALUES(?,?,?)", (title_Data,year_Data,rating_Data))
```

See the docs for [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much , im relatively new to sqlite3 thank you.

Comment: @Noob that's ok! If this helped you, you can mark it as the answer and/or vote it up using the buttons on the left of it.

Comment: Could you help me out with one more thing?

Comment: @Noob Is it related? If so, yes. If not, you might need to open another question.

Comment: its part of the same program but not this question. Ill open another question.